# Will Dispose() be called in a using statement with a null object?

Tags: c#, idisposable, using

Is it safe to use the `using` statement on a (potentially) null object?
Consider the following example:

```
class Test {
    IDisposable GetObject(string name) {
        // returns null if not found
    }

    void DoSomething() {
        using (IDisposable x = GetObject("invalid name")) {
            if (x != null) {
                 // etc...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `Dispose` will be called only if the object is not null, and I will not get a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513035

Comment: To answer your last question directly [from the language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1314-the-using-statement): `If a null resource is acquired, then no call to Dispose is made, and no exception is thrown.`

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Yes, `Dispose()` is only called on non-null objects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Note that even if your variable is null, the using block is executed, and if you reference your variable inside the using block without first null-checking it, you WILL get NullReferenceException. To prevent misinterpretation, this answer should state: "Yes, `Dispose()` is only called on non-null objects".

Comment: The page referenced by the link doesn't mention (anymore?) what happens when the object is null.

Answer (score 48):

The expansion for `using` checks that the object is not `null` before calling `Dispose` on it, so yes, it's safe.

In your case you would get something like:

```
IDisposable x = GetObject("invalid name");
try
{
    // etc...
}
finally
{
    if(x != null)
    {
        x.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You should be ok with it:

```
using ((IDisposable)null) { }
```

No exception thrown here.

Side note: don't mistake this with `foreach` and `IEnumerable` where an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, before Disposing the reference will be null-checked. You can examine yourself by viewing your code in Reflector.

Answer (score -3):

You will not get null reference exception as per my experience. It will be simply ignored.