# Calling methods on a null reference in the context of a using clause is OK?

Tags: c#, null, nullreferenceexception

I was looking at the mvc-mini-profiler designed by the Stack Overflow team on Google Code and one thing on the [getting started](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/%20getting%20started) page struck me as particularly strange:

```
var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current; // it's ok if this is null

using (profiler.Step("Set page title"))
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

How can it be "ok" if profiler is null? It seems to me that calling Step would throw a `NullReferenceException`. In all my years of programming C# I've never known calling a method on a null reference in any context to be "ok". Is this a special case in the context of a using clause?

I can understand this being OK (didn't know it was, but apparently it is?):

```
using (null)
{
    ...
}
```

but calling a method on a null reference seems like it should throw an exception regardless of whether it's in a using clause. Can someone please explain how such a construct is translated behind the scenes, so I can understand why it is OK to do this?

Comment: Is `Step` an extension method or an instance method?

Comment: Bah. If so that would explain everything...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's absolutely *not* OK if `profiler` is null *unless* `profiler.Step` is actually an extension method. The `using` statement doesn't affect that.

As it turns out, the extension method part is exactly what's going on. Lines 584-587 of MiniProfiler.cs:

```
public static IDisposable Step(this MiniProfiler profiler, string name,
                               ProfileLevel level = ProfileLevel.Info)
{
    return profiler == null ? null : profiler.StepImpl(name, level);
}
```

That's how it's okay for `profiler.Step` to be called when `profiler` is null. It's not an instance method - the call translates to:

```
MiniProfilerExtensions.Step(profiler, ...);
```

It's fine for `profiler.Step` to *return* null, as per the second part of your question.

Comment: Facepalming now after Mehrdad asked whether Step was an extension method and I realized it was. Thanks to you both. :)

Answer (score 5):

`Step` must be an [**extension method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), as was my guess in the comment.

Otherwise either your compiler is mutilated or you're hallucinating. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, such a good question. My first reaction was "of course that is ungood" ... but I typed it into VS2010 and seemed happy.

I found a possible answer for you (does that make me an answer proxy?) here: [Using statement with a null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522822/c-using-statement-with-a-null-object)

If it was me, I would write a unit test to validate this behaviour so that if it every changed in the future the test will fail.

See ya