# Mass Dispose, better way?

Tags: c#, dispose

So i am currently disposing many objects when i close my form. Even though it probably disposes it automatically. But still i prefer to follow the "rules" in disposing, hopefully it will stick and help prevent mistakes.

So here is how i currently dispose, which works.

```
        if (connect == true)
        {
            Waloop.Dispose();
            connect = false;
            UninitializeCall();
            DropCall();

        }
        if (KeySend.Checked || KeyReceive.Checked)
        {
            m_mouseListener.Dispose();
            k_listener.Dispose();

        }
        if (NAudio.Wave.AsioOut.isSupported())
        {
            Aut.Dispose();
        }

        if (Wasout != null)
        {
            Wasout.Dispose();
        }
        if (SendStream != null)
        {
            SendStream.Dispose();
        }
```

So basically, the first is if a bool is true, meaning if it isn´t those can be ignore, as they haven´t been made i think.

The others are just ways for me to dispose if it´s there. but it´s not a very good way, i would like to have it in 1 big function, meaning.

Dispose if it´s NOT disposed. or something.
I know that many of them has the "isdisposed" bool, so it should be possible if i can check every object, and dispose if it´s false.

Comment: Do you mean that the entire application closes by `when i close my form` ? If so, easy - do nothing.

Comment: @asawyer: That's easy until 6 months from now when he decides that the form shouldn't be his main form, and all of a sudden he's leaking handles.

Comment: Yes, and as Jim says, which is why i want to be prepared:)

Comment: @JimMischel You have to know where to focus your resources. If that's a strong possibility, sure. If not, move on to something else. You have to strike a balance somewhere.

Comment: Don't write senseless code.  Find out whether an object is disposable from the documentation and whether it is already getting disposed, no point in guessing at it.  If this is a form and the object is not a control or component then high odds that you'll have to dispose it yourself.

Comment: In addition to what Hans said.. it is so quick to just "Go to definition" in Visual Studio to find what an object implements.. there really is no excuse!

Comment: I check which objects can be dispose and which not. But i am just asking for a way to dispose of them easier when i build them up. As some of them can´t be disposed in using. Or well, they Can, but it will be a performance hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a helper method which takes objects which implement `IDisposable` as params?

```
void DisposeAll(params IDisposable[] disposables)
{
  foreach (IDisposable id in disposables)
  {
    if (id != null) id.Dispose();
  }
}
```

When you want to dispose multiple objects, call the method with whatever objects you want to dispose.

```
this.DisposeAll(Wasout, SendStream, m_mouseListener, k_listener);
```

If you want to avoid calling them explicity, then store them all in a `List<>`:

```
private List<IDisposable> _disposables;

void DisposeAll() {
  foreach(IDisposable id in _disposables) {
    if(id != null) id.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Interesting idea, I keep forgetting about the `params` keyword.

Comment: I do´t know how to implement it, but it seems very much like the Invoker Method i got from here. can you show how to just add an object to it for use?

Comment: Ah, is it possible to do something like the Invoker method i have.

    Invoker(() =>
                {
})

?

Comment: This is an answer, though i would like to be able to write it without comma, and more like (Sendstream; "tab" Wasaout;)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a `Disposer` class, that will do the work for you, along these lines:

```
public class Disposer
{
   private List<IDisposable> disposables = new List<IDisposable>();

   public void Register(IDisposable item)
   {
      disposables.Add(item);
   }

   public void Unregister(IDisposable item)
   {
      disposables.Remove(item);
   }

   public void DisposeAll()
   {
      foreach (IDisposable item in disposables)
      {
        item.Dispose();
      }
      disposables.Clear();
   }
}
```

Then, instead of the ugly code in your main class, you can have something like:

```
public class Main
{
   //member field
   private Disposer m_disposer;

   //constructor
   public Main()
   {
       ....
       m_disposer = new Disposer();
       //register any available disposables
       disposer.Register(m_mouseListener);
       disposer.Register(k_listener);
   }

   ...

   public bool Connect()
   {
       ...
       if (isConnected)
       {
           Waloop = ...
           Wasout = ...
           // register additional disposables as they are created
           disposer.Register(Waloop);
           disposer.Register(Wasout);
       }
   }

   ...

   public void Close()
   {
     //disposal
     disposer.DisposeAll();
   }
}
```

Comment: But, then i have to register everything iw ant to dispose, to the disposer when it´s created?
Though, then again, this will look cleaner. A + for that, will give it a try.

Comment: @user2587718: not necessarily. You can just have the disposer as a member variable, and register and unregister stuff as needed.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, i have added it in private disposer blabla.
and am now registering everything like you have done.

Comment: Okay it doesn´t seem to work, i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object, maybe cause it doesn´t have access to the variables. Tried changing them to public, didn´t help though

Comment: @user2587718 added a more complete example

Comment: I see, but i will still get the Object reference error. not sure why.

Comment: If you don't mind using a threadstatic variable, you can define a `T RegisterDisposable<T>(T it) where T:IDisposable` function and use it within object initializers (e.g. `var MyBrush = RegisterDisposable(new SolidBrush());`).  Threadstatic variables are icky, but the above approach makes it easy to ensure that variables get initialized and cleaned up.  VB.NET allows one to eliminate the threadstatic variable, but I don't know how to do so in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). So with your code, it would look something like this:

```
  using (WaloopClass Waloop = new WaloopClass())
  {
        // Some other code here I know nothing about.

        connect = false; // Testing the current value of connect is redundant.
        UninitializeCall();
        DropCall();
  }
```

Note there is now no need to explicitly Dispose Waloop, as it happens automatically at the end of the using statement.

This will help to structure your code, and makes the scope of the Waloop much clearer.

Comment: Using statement make sense in some cases, but not all the time

Comment: I am using the using statement as much as i can where it has performance benefits, which is most of the time, but as Simon says, not all the time.

Comment: I know how to use Using, learned it very recently, and use it as often as i can:)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suppose that the only problem you’re trying to solve is how to write the following in a nicer way:

```
if (Wasout != null)
    Wasout.Dispose();
if (SendStream != null)
    SendStream.Dispose();
```

This is a lot of logic already implemented by the `using` keyword. [`using` checks that the variable is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2522822/429091) before calling `Dispose()` for you. Also, `using` guarantees that thrown exceptions (perhap by `Wasout.Dispose()`) will not interrupt the attempts to call `Dispose()` on the other listed objects (such as `SendStream`). It seems that `using` was intended to allow management of resources based on scoping rules: using `using` as an alternative way to write `o.Dispose()` may be considered an abuse of the language. However, the benefits of `using`’s behavior and the concision it enables are quite valuable. Thus, I recommend to replace such mass statically-written batches of the “`if (o != null) o.Dispose()`” with an “empty” `using`:

```
using (
    IDisposable _Wasout = Wasout,
    _SendStream = SendStream)
{}
```

Note that the order that `Dispose()` is called in is in reverse of how objects are listed in the `using` block. This follows the pattern of cleaning up objects in reverse of their instantiation order. (The idea is that an object instantiated later may refer to an object instantiated earlier. E.g., if you are using a ladder to climb a house, you might want to keep the ladder around so that you can climb back down *before* putting it away—the ladder gets instantiated first and cleaned up last. Uhm, analogies… but, basically, the above is [shorthand for nested `using`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329751/429091). And the unlike objects can be smashed into the same `using` block by writing the `using` in terms of `IDisposable`.)

[dotnetfiddle of `using` managing exceptions.](http://dotnetfiddle.net/DWT9wC)