# Does a C# using statement perform try/finally?

Tags: c#, exception, using, using-statement

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
private void UpdateDB(QuoteDataSet dataSet, Strint tableName)
{
    using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, conn))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataAdapter sqliteAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter())
                {
                    sqliteAdapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);
                }
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

The C# documentation states that with a `using` statement the object within the scope will be disposed and I've seen several places where it's suggested that we don't need to use try/finally clause.

I usually surround my connections with a try/finally, and I always close the connection in the finally clause. Given the above code, is it reasonable to assume that the connection will be closed if there is an exception?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278902/using-statement-vs-try-finally

Comment: Not an answer to your question. Please read about sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[You are correct; the `using` statement compiles to a `try` / `finally` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28VS.71%29.aspx).

The compiler transforms `using(resource) statement;` into the following code:

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

(The cast to `IDisposable` is in case `ResourceType` implements `IDisposable` explicitly.

Comment: what is best to release a resource which can not be instantiated within using statement or being reused or being passed as out param?

Comment: @bjan: It depends on the situation.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you either need to use a try/finally or a using statement. You don't need both.

A [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) is almost the same as a try/finally except that in C# 3 you can't reassign to the variable inside the using block.

```
using (IDisposable d = foo())
{
     d = null; // Error:  Cannot assign to 'd' because it is a 'using variable'
}
```

Previously you could reassign but the original object would still be disposed, not the newly assigned object and you would also get this compile warning:

> Possibly incorrect assignment to local 'd' which is the argument to a using or lock statement. The Dispose call or unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.

Comment: what is best to release a resource which can not be instantiated within using statement or being reused or being passed as out param?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the `using` statement is pretty much just shorthand for a `try ... finally` block.

For example, this code...

```
using (MyDisposableType foo = new MyDisposableType())
{
    foo.DoSomething();
}
```

...would equate to the following...

```
{
    MyDisposableType foo = new MyDisposableType();
    try
    {
        foo.DoSomething();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (foo != null)
            ((IDisposable)foo).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that the connection will be closed if you get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Using() ensures that the item instantiated within the parameters will be disposed of regardless of that happens within the associated code block. This includes closing the database connection assuming that `SQLiteConnection` handles its disposal correctly.