# How to catch and log exception inside Using statement without using try-catch?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch, using

As I know that Using statement has built in implementation of Dispose() and Try-Catch. So I want to know few things

1. Is it possible to log an exception inside using statement without
   using try-catch block , either inside or outside the statement. If
   not, then why its built in to the statement.
2. Nested or overuse of try-catch is not preferred, then why such model
   preferred to use.

   ```
           using (some_resource)
           {
               try
               {
               }
               catch
               {
               }
               finally
               {
                   //my exception logging mechanism
               }
           }
   ```

will become

```
            try
            {
                try
                {
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    //my exception logging mechanism
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                //some_resource.Dispose()
            }
```

Comment: `using` does not translate to `try-catch`, only `try-finally`.

Comment: Shouldn't the "exception logging mechanism" be insinde the 'catch', not 'finally'?

Comment: from where do you derive your preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `using` statement involves `try`/`finally`; there is no `catch`. But frankly, your concern is overkill; multiply-nested and complex `try`/`catch`/`finally` is "undesirable" because:

- it makes the code hard to read
- and even harder to get right (most people get it wrong, alas)
- it is frequently misused
- it suggests your method is doing too much

With `using`, this isn't an issue; it makes the intent very clean, without adding complexity or concern.

I would just use:

```
using (some_resource) {
    try {
        // some code
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogIt(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using compiles to Try{}Finally{}. See the following question: [Does a C# using statement perform try/finally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710032/does-a-c-sharp-using-statement-perform-try-finally)

The reason for this is so that the resource will be disposed of regardless of if an exception is thrown. Resource disposal is the purpose of the using statement.

The correct implementation is:

```
using(Resource myresource = GetResource())
{
    try
    {}
    catch(Exception e)
    { //Maybe log the exception here when it happens?
    }
}
```