# Why C# compiler copies variable for locking?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, locking, thread-synchronization

My original code is such like

```cs
Object mylock = new object();
void Test()
{
    lock(mylock)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Compiled into the following code

```cs
void Test
{
    object obj = mylock;  // add a temporary variable
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTaken);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know why add a temporary variable rather than use original variable directly as follows.

```cs
void Test
{
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(mylock, ref lockTaken);  // use original variable directly
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(mylock);  // use original variable directly
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because otherwise mylock could be changed in another thread. And you really don't want to unlock the wrong object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several C# constructs ([`using`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710032/does-a-c-sharp-using-statement-perform-try-finally), `lock`) get transformed into final code that way to prevent re-assingnment of the variable used. You really don't want `finally` section to act on something different than the value the original operation started with.

Sample of the code that would behave incorrectly if compiler simply uses current value of `myLock` in `finally` section:

```
 object myLock = new object();

 lock(myLock)
 {
    myLock = new object(); 
    ...
 }
```

Note that compiling such code also brings CS0728 warning because attempting to change lock variable will be ignored.