# Are streams disposed of automatically in a try/catch statement?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

If I create a stream inside of the try block and an exception is raised does the stream automatically get disposed of? For example:

```
try
{
   Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
   //Error Occurs
   stream.Close();
}
catch
{
   //Handle Error
}
```

If this is not the way to do it can you please suggest an approach?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you need to use `finally`

```
Stream stream;
try
{
   stream = response.GetResponseStream();
   //Error Occurs
}
catch
{
   //Handle Error
}
finally
{
    if(stream != null)
        stream.Close();
}
```

Or, wrap your `Stream` declaration/definition in a `using` statement, which calls `Close()` automatically:

```
try
{
    using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        //Error happens
    }
    //stream.Dispose(), which calls stream.Close(), is called by compiler here
}
catch
{
   //Handle Error
}
```

---

Note that my two examples are not *exactly* equivalent - in the first, the exception is handled before `steam.Close()` is called, in the second the exception is handled after.

Answer (score 5):

The stream will not automatically close in this case.

If you wanted to ensure it closes in this context you'll want to use `finally` to ensure closure.

Alternatively I'd wrap the whole stream in a using.

```
using(Steam stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
 // Do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, use a `using` block.  It calls Dispose automatically when block finishes, even if an error occurs.

eg.

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   // do something with stream
}
```

It's the same as:

```
Stream stream = null;
try
{
    stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // do something with stream
}
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
        stream.Dispose();
}
```

There are many examples on the net.  A quick Google revealed the following already on stackoverflow:  ['using' statement vs 'try finally'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278902/using-statement-vs-try-finally)

Answer (score 3):

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
}
```

`Dispose()` is called on scope exit.  This is the correct idiom for ensuring cleanup of `IDisposable` objects.

Answer (score 2):

using(resource) statement will take care of calling dispose.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. It's best to close all resources in a `finally` block if you have some exception handling logic around your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, to always ensure disposal, regardless of exceptions, you use:

```
try
{
   Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
   //Error Occurs
}
catch
{
   //Handle Error
}
finally
{
   if(stream!=null)
       stream.Close();
}
```

or simply:

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream implements IDisposable interface.
You can use using() statements where the class implements IDisposable.
This will automatically take care of closing and disposing the object without writing finally.

```
        try
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                //Error happens
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Handle Error
        }
```